# google page insights api screenshot - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, google-api, laravel-5.4, google-pagespeed

Im having trouble getting the Google API PageSpeed Insights screenshot that they provide of the website when hitting the API. I have looked at other examples, but none seem to work for me.

This is what I get back when hitting the API.
[image: Google API Endpoint]

And this is my controller:

```
   public function fetch() {

        $key = env('GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_KEY');
        $website = request('website_url');

        $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();

        $res = $client->request('GET', 'https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v2/runPagespeed?url=http://' .$website. '&key=' . $key . '&screenshot=true');

        if ($res->getStatusCode() == 200) {
            $result = json_decode($res->getBody());

            $data    = str_replace('_','/',$result->screenshot->data);
            $data    = str_replace('-','+',$data);
            $decoded = base64_decode($data);

            return view('api.index', compact('result', 'decoded'));

        } else {
            return redirect()->back();
        }
    }
```

I try to call it in the front end like this:

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'{{ $decoded }}">
// And like this
<img src="{{ $decoded }}">
```

But just get an empty src=""

Comment: Your first `<img>` tag looks like it's missing an `'` at the end.

Comment: Didnt see that. I fixed it. Still is coming back empty though.

Comment: Is the data being output to the page when you view source? And why are you replacing `_` and `-` in the data?

Comment: Can post the actual url you're sending? That might help us understand the  problem better.

Comment: I have updated my question at the bottom with the page source im getting.

Comment: When you say URL im sending, you mean the website im inserting in the searchbar to get my results?

Comment: Yes.. just store that 2nd argument in a variable and print it. so, we can check independently

Comment: I updated my question, thats what I get when I DD just the $data

Comment: sorry, that was not my question. what is the website you're using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

This is what I did in my controller (not much changing):

```
$result = json_decode($res->getBody());

            $data    = str_replace('_','/',$result->screenshot->data);
            $data    = str_replace('-','+',$data);
```

This is how I called it in front-end:

```
 <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,{{ $data }}">
```